# Weird <T> Activator Question

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, class

I'm sorry, but a while ago I wrote a piece of code that was so nice. And now I'm trying to remember it for a new project.

All I can remember about it is that it looked something like this:

```
public static Create<T>() *something missing here* : *Something missing here*
{
     // add methods etc here. I also think I remember something like " Activator.CreateInstance" being used. But I'm not sure.
}
```

Has anybody written code like this before? Basically what it did was it created a control and passed it back to another project.

Thank you
jt

Comment: @j-t-s: Please don't forget to mark-as-answer the post that answered your question.

Comment: Yeah, it's been on my mind for ages lol. I had to buy more prepaid internet to come back on here to mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it looked similar to this:

```
public static Create<T>() where T : new()
{
    return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
}
```

**Some explanations:**

- `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T))` creates an object of type `T`. You could optionally pass parameters to the constructor being called (check the [reference documentation for a parameter overview for `Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance%28VS.80%29.aspx)), but since this should work for almost any `T`, providing constructor arguments is too specific and not a good idea.
- That's why `where T : new()` is needed. This puts a `new()` constraint on type parameter `T`. What this means is that this method is only valid for types `T` that provide a parameter-less ("default") constructor.

---

**P.S.:** Note that you only need `Activator.CreateInstance` when all you have to work on is a `System.Type`. In the above example, you actually have a type name `T`, so `new T()` would be preferable. See @Guffa's answer for this.

Comment: you can also use Activator.CreateInstance<T>()

Comment: Thanks! That's the one! :D I think my memory got temporarily deaded, lol.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a condition for the generic type. If you specify that it has to have a constructor, you don't even need Activator to call it:

```
public static Create<T>() where T : new() {
  return new T();
}
```

If you want to use parameters in the constructor call, you would use the Activator, but then the condition that the class should have a parameterless constructor is pointless.